# IO Error but badblocks and fsck are happy

Tags: filesystems, lvm, io, luks, whole-drive-encryption

I have an ext4 partition with the following underlaying stack:

- sda1 and sdb1 are together in a RAID1, resulting in md0
- md0 is LUKS-encrypted, resulting in md0_crypt
- on top of md0_crypt is a single LVM volume mv0_vg_media, mounted under /home/media

When performing `cp /home/media/hierarchy/photo.jpg /tmp` I get an IO error (but just for like 20 files, out of several ten thousands).

Hoever, when I attempt to debug the problem:

- Both dmesg and the syslog stay clean when the IO Error occurs. (EDIT: clarification: This means that there is not any disk-related output logged in dmesg or syslog, even if the log is active with `--follow` option while the read errors occur.)
- Badblocks on sda and sdb do not reveal any errors
- fsck on `/dev/mapper/md0_vg_media` only outputs "could be narrower. IGNORED." warnings but no errors and the autocorrect option does not fix anything.

I'm puzzled. I could just delete those files and re-sync them, but that's a bad idea if I don't know what the problem actually is.

How can I further debug this?

EDIT:

From the comments and further research, I tried the following approaches (in vain) with the following results:

- `mdadm --examine /dev/sda` (same for sdb) returns: `/dev/sda: MBR Magic : aa55 Partition[0] : 3907029167 sectors at 1 (type ee)`
- `mdadm --examine-badblocks /dev/sda` (same for sdb) returns: `mdadm: mbr metadata does not support badblocks`
- `cat /sys/block/md0/md/mismatch_cnt` contains the value `0` (zero)
- `echo 'check' > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action` performs the check but does not reveal any errors. Dmesg has two entries: `[734796.807172] md: data-check of RAID array md0` and then immediately below: `[754370.977181] md: md0: data-check done.`

Comment: what's the specific error messages in dmesg? for md raid also check `mdadm --examine` and `mdadm --examine-badblocks` on `sd[ab]*`. if encryption is a LUKS 2 device with integrity enabled it could also be bad checksums.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question with the details.